# What is the advantage of following Inheritance

Tags: inheritance, exception, python-3.6

I frequently read code of the libraries

I have come across the following code snippets.
The code snippets are from the python schedule library

I have searched internet but haven't found satisfactory answers

```
class ScheduleError(Exception):
    """Base schedule exception"""
    pass


class ScheduleValueError(ScheduleError):
    """Base schedule value error"""
    pass


class IntervalError(ScheduleValueError):
    """An improper interval was used"""
    pass
```

I would like to know what is the advantage of inheriting from a class which has no attributes or methods in it

I can benefit from both theoretical and practical explantions

Comment: In the case of errors, it lets you catch them appropriately. Top level error handler for the whole program? `except Exception:` lets you see every unhandled error. Middle tier function? You can check for any schedule-related problems with `except ScheduleError:`. And so on.

Answer (score 0):

the idea is that you can fine-tune the exceptions you want to catch:

```
try:
    f() # may raise one of ScheduleError
except IntervalError:
    # do something about it
```

having the hierarchy as above you can select which of the exceptions you want to handle in your `except` clause. you might even catch everything that may go wrong in `f` with `except Exception` (not recommended!).

the whole [exception hierarchy in pyhton](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy) is well documented.

Comment: Yeah . But in particular i would like to know why ScheduleValueError needs to be inherited from ScheduleError.  To make it comfortable handling exceptions we can still defin ScheduleValueError by inheriting it From Exception Base Class.  and we would still be able to catch separate exceptions.  so basic question is what is the benefit of inheriting from ScheduleError Class (given that it has no attributes or methods whatssoever)

Comment: i do not know the use-case. there may be a good reason for that. but that's almost impossible to say without knowing the library...

Comment: python schedule library. There is only one file and the code is very simple. around 400 lines. I read the code but couldn't figure out it's significance

Comment: just guessing: it seems like `schedule_value` is a parameter of a method; if part of that value is an interval, then it would make sense if `IntervalError` were also a `ScheduleValueError`